# ¿Por qué Django intenta abrir una URL que no le indico?

Tags: html, python, django

**¡Hola Comunidad!**

Estoy creando un pequeño blog con Django, en el cual tengo una sola aplicación. Ocurre que ya tengo definido gran parte del blog, esto es:

- La vista de Inicio.
- Vistas para las categorías de cada publicación.
- Vista para cada uno de los posts
- Entre otras

Ahora que he querido agregar la vista de "Acerca del Autor", cuando se debería redireccionar a su respectiva plantilla HTML, Django termina por redireccionarse hacía otra plantilla, el cual me genera un error de tipo `NoReverseMatch`

**Simplificando el código, esto es:**

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post, Autor, Categoria

class Inicio(ListView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'post': Post.objects.get(titulo='NombreDelPost')
        }
        return render(request, 'PaginaWebApp/home.html', context)

class PostSimple(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, slug_post, *args, **kwargs)
        
        context = {
            'post': Post.objects.filter(slug_post=slug_post)
        }

        return render(request, 'PaginaWebApp/page-simple.html', context)

class PostsCategoria(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, categoria, *args, **kwargs):
            # Vista que muestra cada una de las categorías dentro del blog
            context = {
                'categorias': Categoria.objects.get(categoria=categoria)
            }

            return render(request, 'PaginaWebApp/posts-category.html', context)

class AcercaAutor(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, slug_autor, *args, **kwargs):

        context = {
            'autor': Autor.objects.get(slug_autor=slug_autor)
        } 

        return render(request, 'PaginaWebApp/page-author.html', context)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from PaginaWebApp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Inicio.as_view(), name='home'),
    # [Aquí van las URL hacia las otras plantillas del proyecto (ellas funcionan bien)]
    # A continuación las conflictivas:
    path('posts-<categoria>/', views.PostsCategoria.as_view(), name='posts-category'),
    path('<slug:slug_post>/', views.PostSimple.as_view(), name='page-simple'),
    path('acerca-de-<slug:slug_autor>/', views.AcercaAutor.as_view(), name='page-author'),
]
```

Tengo una plantilla llamada "base.html" que heredan todas las demás.

En la plantilla de Inicio, llamada "home.html" podemos conseguir, entre otras cosas, lo siguiente:

```
<!-- AQUI VAN OTRAS ETIQUETAS QUE REDIRECCIONAN A OTRAS URL  -->
<h4><a href="{% url 'page-category' categorias.categoria %}" title="">Ver los posts de {{categorias.categoria}}</a></h4>
<h4><a href="{% url 'page-simple' post.slug_post %}" title="">{{post.titulo}}</a></h4>
<h4><a href="{% url 'page-author' autor.slug_autor %}" title="">Por: {{autor.nombre}}</a></h4>
```

Como mencioné anteriormente, al ingresar a la ventana de inicio "home.html" poseo una serie de etiquetas "a" que redireccionan a diversas plantillas, pero específicamente cuando selecciono a que vaya a la URL de la plantilla page-author.html, por alguna razón Django interpreta que debe redireccionarse a page-category y me genera el error descrito.

```
Reverse for 'posts-category' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts\\-(?P<categoria>[^/]+)/$']
```

He revisado exhaustivamente cada plantilla HTML y todas están correctamente redireccionadas a las URL correspondientes.

***Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas y comentarios.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error estaba en el llamado a las plantillas a través del archivo urls.py, ya que en cada uno de los path se hacía referencia a otra plantilla, el cual fallaba ya que no se disponía de los argumentos del context. Para solventarlo, simplemente tengo que realizar las siguientes modificaciones:

```
path('posts/<categoria>/categoria/', views.PostsCategoria.as_view(), name = 'posts-category'),
path('posts/<slug:slug_post>/', views.PostSimple.as_view(), name = 'page-simple'),
path('autores/<slug:slug_autor>/', views.AcercaAutor.as_view(), name = 'page-author'),
```

Answer (score 1):

pro me gustaría ver la plantilla de acerca de pero si no estoy mal en esa plantilla debes de tener algún link que te lleve a posts-category. Aunque pensándolo bien podría ser problema del base ya que como estas llamando la base en todas las demás vistas como no tienes por contexto a las categorías ni los post te van a salir esos errores porque no encuentra esos ids. Tienes que pasarle por contexto esas variables. No es que te este redireccionando a otro sitio es que te está pidiendo esas variables para que pueda correr sin problema. Me cuentas!